# Est-ce que le mot servir-boy est français ?

Tags: mots-composés, suisse, définition

J'aimerais savoir si c'est un régionalisme suisse ou si c'est un mot que l'on utilise aussi en France.

Comment: nota : Un régionalisme... je veux dire un mot utilisé dans une région de la francophonie EST un mot français. Qu'il soit ou non utilisé dans l'hexagone. Pour charrier les français de France relativement à ne tenir pour français que les mots issus de l'état-nation, les Québécois les traitent... d'hexagonalismes... Et un hexagonalisme, vis à vis du français... n'a ni plus ni moins d'autorité qu'un helvétisme, un belgicisme ou un québéq... hmm! un mot français! pardon!

Comment: Je n'avais jamais entendu *servir-boy* mais toujours *service-boy*. Apparement, les deux semblent répandus en Suisse romande.

Answer (score 1):

Jamais entendu en France.

Cette [page](http://mapage.noos.fr/r.ferreol/langage/fr-ch.htm) laisse penser qu'il s'agit d'un régionalisme suisse-romand.